# Regex to match 2 digits colon 2 digits

Tags: regex

I need a regex to validate data has been entered in the following format: 22:33.

Comment: `\d` is one digit. `\d\d` is two digits. `:` is :. I let you finish.

Comment: Yes but that starts to be complex...

Comment: Looks like a time, do you also need to limit to 23 and 59?

Comment: McKnigh. Look at the regex tag : it specifies you should precise the regex tool or flavor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use thjis regular expression `^\d{2}:\d{2}$`

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't specify any particular regex type or where it might occur in input; this is an example `[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]`.

If you want to match the whole input to just being exactly on that format `^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]$` .. etc.

Comment: Honest question : Are there common flavors where `\d` isn't defined ?

Comment: @dystroy There is a world beyond Windows ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`^\d\d:\d\d$` should do the trick.